# How do I build a regex to match a pattern while excluding certain known words that would match the pattern

Tags: regex

How do I build a regex to match a pattern while excluding certain known words that would match the pattern. In example I have this string:

**I like to d.r.e.a.m at going to do h i k i n g.**

and I have the following regex: **\b(.{1,2}(\s|.|-|_)){2,}**

This matches:

**to d.r.e.a.m at**

**to do h i k i n g.**

What I want is to change this regex in a way to match:

**d.r.e.a.m**

**h i k i n g.**

If I change it to this **\b([^(to)]{1,2}(\s|.|-|_)){2,}**

it will partially work but it would exclude individual letters like 
't' 'o' instead of the entire word 'to'

How to solve this?

Comment: First off, how did you get that output with your regex? I'm getting `g.` and `g.` in the groups not `to d.r.e.a.m at` and `to do h i k i n g`.

Comment: What about `(?:\b[^\W_][\s._-]){2,}`?

Comment: Do you have words like `d.r.e_a-m`? If yes should they match? What  about `hi.k.i.n.g`?

Comment: Is the point at the end of `h i k i n g` necessarily? If not then `\b\w([\s._-])\w(?:\1\w)+`.

Comment: In which programming language are you trying this?

Comment: I am using this http://www.rubular.com/r/nZjJlfaLWa to try things out.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov that gets close to what I need but something like this would be missed: i.e. "to do hi ki ng" should match on "hi ki ng" and it doesn't

Comment: Try [`\b(?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2}(?:\W(?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2})*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ufvj2w/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. This works 99.9% for what I need now :). It doesn't cover stuff like h_a_p_p_y though. Any idea how to change it to cover that?

Comment: What language will you be using the pattern in? See [this Rubular demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/J9dTk9blje).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\b(?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2}(?:[\W_](?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2})*\b/
```

See [this Rubular demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/B4LZ20JaPE)

It matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2}` - followed with a 1 or 2 word char word not equal to `I`, `at`, `to` or `do`
- `(?:[\W_](?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2})*` - 0+ repetitions of:

  - `[\W_]` - a non-word char or `_`
  - `(?!(?:I|at|[td]o)\b)\w{1,2}` - see above
- `\b` - a word boundary.